# How to bind TabCompleteNext/TabCompletePrevious in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, keyboard-shortcuts, readline

I tried the following commands to bind Ctrl-N and Ctrl-P in PowerShell 7.2.4, but they have no effect - new bindings do not work.

```
Remove-PSReadLineKeyHandler Tab
Remove-PSReadLineKeyHandler Tab -ViMode Command
Remove-PSReadLineKeyHandler Shift-Tab
Remove-PSReadLineKeyHandler Shift-Tab -ViMode Command

Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler Ctrl+N -Function TabCompleteNext
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler Ctrl+P -Function TabCompletePrevious
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler Ctrl+N -Function TabCompleteNext -ViMode Command
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler Ctrl+P -Function TabCompletePrevious -ViMode Command

Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler

...

Completion functions
====================

Key             Function            Description
---             --------            -----------
Ctrl+Spacebar   PossibleCompletions Display the possible completions without changing the input
<Ctrl+Spacebar> PossibleCompletions Display the possible completions without changing the input
Ctrl+N          TabCompleteNext     Complete the input using the next completion
<Ctrl+N>        TabCompleteNext     Complete the input using the next completion
Ctrl+P          TabCompletePrevious Complete the input using the previous completion
<Ctrl+P>        TabCompletePrevious Complete the input using the previous completion
```

I also tried the following, but no effect:

```
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler Ctrl+N -Function ViTabCompleteNext
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler Ctrl+P -Function ViTabCompletePrevious
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler Ctrl+N -Function ViTabCompleteNext -ViMode Command
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler Ctrl+P -Function ViTabCompletePrevious -ViMode Command
```

Any idea how to bind TabCompleteNext/TabCompletePrevious in PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This PowerShell command is very finicky.
The problem is that you have specified "Ctrl+N" but are
typing "Ctrl+n".

This command works for me:

```
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Key Ctrl+n -Function TabCompleteNext
```

Source :
[Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Key Ctrl+U not working #1396](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/issues/1396).

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea that the case matters :)